# How to model recursive function types?

Tags: scala

I'm curious how this code would be modelled in Scala.

This is in golang, and it is a recursive function type:

```
type walkFn func(*int) walkFn
```

So the above is just a defintion of the type, a walk function is a function that takes a pointer to an integer, and returns a walk function.

An example implementation would be:

```
func walkForward(i *int) walkFn {
    *i += rand.Intn(6)
    return pickRandom(walkEqual, walkBackward)
}

func walkBackward(i *int) walkFn {
    *i += -rand.Intn(6)
    return pickRandom(walkEqual, walkForward)
}
```

You can run code like this here: http://play.golang.org/p/621lCnySmy

Is it possible to write something like this pattern in Scala?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible. You can use existential types to "cheat" scala's cyclic reference restriction:

```
type A[T <: A[_]] = Int => (Int, T)

lazy val walkEqual: A[A[_]] = (i: Int) => 
  (i + Random.nextInt(7) - 3, if (Random.nextBoolean) walkForward else walkBackward)

lazy val walkForward: A[A[_]] = (i: Int) =>  
  (i + Random.nextInt(6), if (Random.nextBoolean) walkEqual else walkBackward)

lazy val walkBackward: A[A[_]] = (i: Int) => 
  (i - Random.nextInt(6), if (Random.nextBoolean) walkEqual else walkForward)

def doWalk(count: Int, walkFn: A[_] = walkEqual, progress: Int = 0): Unit =
  if (count > 0) {
    val (nextProgress, nextStep: A[_] @unchecked) = walkFn(progress)
    println(nextProgress)
    doWalk(count - 1, nextStep, nextProgress)
  }
```

Result:

```
scala> doWalk(10)
2
5
2
0
-3
-5
-4
-8
-8
-11
```

Or like in @Travis Brown addition:

```
val locations = Stream.iterate[(Int,A[_] @unchecked)](walkEqual(0)) {
   case (x: Int, f: A[_]) => f(x)
}.map(_._1)

scala> locations.take(20).toList
res151: List[Int] = List(-1, 1, 1, 4, 1, -2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, -1, -2, -4, -2, -1, 2, 1, -1, -2)
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail the first line in detail please?  T is a subclass of A, but what does A[_} mean?  Can you please be explicit in what the input and output of the A is?  I get confused easily :)

Comment: `A[_]` is an existential type which means undefined bound here. So, `A[T :< A[_]]` means actually that `T` should be `A` or something smaller and it can be only A actually - so that's the trick. I have to use `A[A[_]] `(which  in this context means A which returns A which returns don't know what) as scala doesn't allow infinite recursion of type, but actually there is a [way to do such things](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/).

Answer (score 5):

One of the sad facts of Scala is that recursive type aliases are not supported. Doing the following in the REPL yields the following:

```
scala> type WalkFn = Function[Int, WalkFn]
<console>:7: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type WalkFn
       type WalkFn = Function[Int, WalkFn]
                                   ^
```

Another note is that Scala does not allow you to modify values by reference (generally frowned upon, nay, loathed entirely in the functional-programming-paradigm).

However, don't dismay! There are other options. Traits can be self-referential, and functions are simply classes in Scala. So we can model the generic recursive WalkFn with traits. Also, we can embrace immutable values and have our function return the next progress, rather than mutate a parameter by reference.

Since the following contains cyclical references (WalkForward -> WalkBackward, WalkBackward -> WalkForward, etc.), you'll need to type `:paste` into the scala `REPL` prior to running the following example (so the Scala compiler will compile all 3 `Walk{Forward,Backward,Equal}` implementations in one step.

First:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
```

Now, paste the code:

```
import scala.util.Random

object Helpers {
  def pickRandom[A](items: A*) =
    items(Random.nextInt(items.length))
}

trait WalkFn extends (Int => (Int, WalkFn)) {}

object WalkForward extends WalkFn {
  def apply(i: Int) =
    ( i + Random.nextInt(6),
      Helpers.pickRandom(WalkEqual, WalkBackward) )
}

object WalkEqual extends WalkFn {
  def apply(i: Int) =
    ( i + (Random.nextInt(7) - 3),
      Helpers.pickRandom(WalkForward, WalkBackward) )
}

object WalkBackward extends WalkFn {
  def apply(i: Int) =
    ( Random.nextInt(6) - 3,
      Helpers.pickRandom(WalkEqual, WalkForward) )
}

def doWalk(count: Int, walkFn: WalkFn = WalkEqual, progress: Int = 0): Unit =
  if (count > 0) {
    val (nextProgress, nextStep) = walkFn(progress)
    println(nextProgress)
    doWalk(count - 1, nextStep, nextProgress)
  }

doWalk(20)
```

Then, per instructions, hit `ctrl-D`.

Enjoy the functional drunken stagger!

Comment: Nice answer, but (not *yet* being familiar with Scala): What do you need the `Helpers` object for? Is it just a namespace, or does any convention prevent you from making a top-level `def`inition?

Comment: @Bergi all `def``'s are methods in scala (they are explicitly/implicitly converting to Function objects by eta-expansion). So every method shoud be placed inside some object. By the way, Scala REPL (and built-in interpreter itself) creates synthetic object, so you can define methods right inside REPL loop, but people usually use objects to make code ready to be compiled by scalac without changes.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it's more idiomatic in Scala to factor out the iteration part. So for example we can define a state machine:

```
import scala.util.Random

sealed trait Walker {
  def i: Int
  def advance: Walker
}

case class WalkEqual(i: Int) extends Walker {
  def advance = {
    val next = i + Random.nextInt(7) - 3
    if (Random.nextBoolean) WalkForward(next) else WalkBackward(next)
  }
}

case class WalkForward(i: Int) extends Walker {
  def advance = {
    val next = i + Random.nextInt(6)
    if (Random.nextBoolean) WalkEqual(next) else WalkBackward(next)
  }
}

case class WalkBackward(i: Int) extends Walker {
  def advance = {
    val next = i - Random.nextInt(6)
    if (Random.nextBoolean) WalkEqual(next) else WalkForward(next)
  }
}
```

And then we can write the following:

```
val locations = Stream.iterate[Walker](WalkEqual(0))(_.advance).map(_.i)
```

This is an infinite stream of locations that our walker visits. We can use it like this:

```
scala> locations.take(10).foreach(println)
0
0
-1
2
1
0
-5
-5
-10
-6
```

We could also take a finite number of these and collect them in a concretely-realized collection (such as a list) by writing `locations.take(100).toList`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a class, and then methods like WalkEqual, WalkForward as oppose to having them in case classes?

Comment: Another valid approach, however this has the disadvantage of being less generic (rather than using the existing type of function, we've created a new type.) Now we lose operations defined on functions, and things that take functions.