# Parsing text and representing it with tokens using Scala

Tags: scala

I'm getting frustrated trying to convert a small part of the Golang templating language to Scala.

Below are the key parts of the lex.go source code: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/parse/lex.go

The tests are here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/parse/lex_test.go

Basically this "class" takes a string and returns an Array of "itemType".  In the template string, the start and end of special tokens is using curly braces `{{ and }}`.

For for example:

```
"{{for}}"
```

returns an array of 4 items:

```
item{itemLeftDelim, 0, "{{" }   // scala case class would be Item(ItemLeftDelim, 0, "")
item{itemIdentifier, 0, "for"}
item{itemRightDelim, 0, "}}"}
item{itemEOF, 0, ""}
```

The actual call would look like:

```
l := lex("for", `{{for}}`, "{{", "}}")      // you pass in the start and end delimeters {{ and }}

for {
    item := l.nextItem()
    items = append(items, item)
    if item.typ == itemEOF || item.typ == itemError {
        break
    }
}
return
```

The key parts of the source code are below:

```
// itemType identifies the type of lex items.
type itemType int

const (
    itemError        itemType = iota // error occurred; value is text of error

    itemEOF

    itemLeftDelim  // left action delimiter
    // .............. skipped
)

const (
    leftDelim    = "{{"
    rightDelim   = "}}"
    leftComment  = "/*"
    rightComment = "*/"
)

// item represents a token or text string returned from the scanner.
type item struct {
    typ itemType // The type of this item.
    pos Pos      // The starting position, in bytes, of this item in the input string.
    val string   // The value of this item.
}

// stateFn represents the state of the scanner as a function that returns the next state.
type stateFn func(*lexer) stateFn


// lexer holds the state of the scanner.
type lexer struct {
    name       string    // the name of the input; used only for error reports
    input      string    // the string being scanned
    leftDelim  string    // start of action
    rightDelim string    // end of action
    state      stateFn   // the next lexing function to enter
    pos        Pos       // current position in the input
    start      Pos       // start position of this item
    width      Pos       // width of last rune read from input
    lastPos    Pos       // position of most recent item returned by nextItem
    items      chan item // channel of scanned items
    parenDepth int       // nesting depth of ( ) exprs
}



// lex creates a new scanner for the input string.
func lex(name, input, left, right string) *lexer {
    if left == "" {
        left = leftDelim
    }
    if right == "" {
        right = rightDelim
    }
    l := &lexer{
        name:       name,
        input:      input,
        leftDelim:  left,
        rightDelim: right,
        items:      make(chan item),
    }
    go l.run()
    return l
}

// run runs the state machine for the lexer.
func (l *lexer) run() {
    for l.state = lexText; l.state != nil; {
        l.state = l.state(l)
    }
}

// nextItem returns the next item from the input.
func (l *lexer) nextItem() item {
    item := <-l.items
    l.lastPos = item.pos
    return item
}



// emit passes an item back to the client.
func (l *lexer) emit(t itemType) {
    l.items <- item{t, l.start, l.input[l.start:l.pos]}
    l.start = l.pos
}


// lexText scans until an opening action delimiter, "{{".
func lexText(l *lexer) stateFn {
    for {
        if strings.HasPrefix(l.input[l.pos:], l.leftDelim) {
            if l.pos > l.start {
                l.emit(itemText)
            }
            return lexLeftDelim
        }
        if l.next() == eof {
            break
        }
    }
    // Correctly reached EOF.
    if l.pos > l.start {
        l.emit(itemText)
    }
    l.emit(itemEOF)
    return nil
}

// next returns the next rune in the input.
func (l *lexer) next() rune {
    if int(l.pos) >= len(l.input) {
        l.width = 0
        return eof
    }
    r, w := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(l.input[l.pos:])
    l.width = Pos(w)
    l.pos += l.width
    return r
}


// lexLeftDelim scans the left delimiter, which is known to be present.
func lexLeftDelim(l *lexer) stateFn {
    l.pos += Pos(len(l.leftDelim))
    if strings.HasPrefix(l.input[l.pos:], leftComment) {
        return lexComment
    }
    l.emit(itemLeftDelim)
    l.parenDepth = 0
    return lexInsideAction
}

// lexRightDelim scans the right delimiter, which is known to be present.
func lexRightDelim(l *lexer) stateFn {
    l.pos += Pos(len(l.rightDelim))
    l.emit(itemRightDelim)
    return lexText
}


// there are more stateFn
```

So I was able to write the item and itemType:

```
case class Item(typ: ItemType, pos: Int, v: String)


sealed trait ItemType

case object ItemError extends ItemType
case object ItemEOF extends ItemType
case object ItemLeftDelim extends ItemType
...
..
.
```

The stateFn and Lex definitions:

```
trait StateFn extends (Lexer => StateFn) {
}
```

**I'm basically really stuck on the main parts here. So things seem to be kicked of like this:**

1. A Lex is created, then "go l.run()" is called.
2. Run is a loop, which keeps looping until EOF or an error is found.
   The loop initializes with lexText, which scans until it finds an {{, and then it sends a message to a channel with all the preceding text of type 'itemText', passing it an 'item'.  It then returns the function lexLeftDelim.   lexLeftDelim does the same sort of thing, it sends a message 'item' of type itemLeftDelim.
3. It keeps parsing the string until it reaches EOF basically.

I can't think in scala that well, but I know I can use an Actor here to pass it a message 'Item'.

The part of returning a function, I asked I got some good ideas here: [How to model recursive function types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129608/how-to-model-recursive-function-types)

Even after this, I am really frustrated and I can seem to glue these concepts together.
I'm not looking for someone to implement the entire thing for me, but if someone could write just enough code to parse a simple string like "{{}}" that would be awesome.  And if they could explain why they did a certain design that would be great.

I created a case class for Lex:

```
case class Lex(
    name: String,
    input: String,
    leftDelim: String,
    rightDelim: String,
    state: StateFn,
    var pos: Int = 0,
    var start: Int = 0, 
    var width: Int = 0,
    var lastPos: Int = 0,
    var parenDepth: Int = 0
    ) {

    def next(): Option[String] = {
        if (this.pos >= this.input.length) {
            this.width = 0
            return None
        }
        this.width = 1
        val nextChar = this.input.drop(this.pos).take(1)
        this.pos += 1
        Some(nextChar)
    }

}
```

The first stateFn is LexText and so far I have:

```
object LexText extends StateFn {
    def apply(l: Lexer) = {
        while {
            if (l.input.startsWith(l.leftDelim)) {
                if (l.pos > l.start) {
                    // ????????? emit itemText using an actor?
                }
                return LexLeftDelim
            }
            if (l.next() == None) {
                break
            }
        }

        if(l.pos > l.start) {
            // emit itemText
        }
        // emit EOF
        return None // ?? nil? how can I support an Option[StateFn]
    }
}
```

I need guidance on getting the Actor's setup, along with the main run loop:

```
func (l *lexer) run() {
    for l.state = lexText; l.state != nil; {
        l.state = l.state(l)
    }
}
```

This is an interesting problem domain that I tried to tackle using Scala, and so far I am a bit confused hoping some else finds it interesting and can work with what little I have so far and provide some code and critique if I am doing it correctly or not.

I know deep down I shouldn't be mutating, but I'm still on the first few pages of the functional book :)

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: need help writing the code to parse a string, and convert it to tokens similiar to lex.go

Answer (score 3):

If you translate the go code literally into Scala, you'll get very unidiomatic piece of code. You'll probably get much more maintainable (and shorter!) Scala version by using [parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators). There are plenty of resources about them on the internet.

---

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

sealed trait ItemType
case object LeftDelim extends ItemType
case object RightDelim extends ItemType
case object Identifier extends ItemType

case class Item(ty: ItemType, token: String)

object ItemParser extends RegexParsers {
  def left: Parser[Item]  = """\{\{""".r ^^ { _ => Item(LeftDelim, "{{") }
  def right: Parser[Item] = """\}\}""".r ^^ { _ => Item(RightDelim, "}}") }
  def ident: Parser[Item] = """[a-z]+""".r ^^ { x => Item(Identifier, x) }

  def item: Parser[Item] = left | right | ident

  def items: Parser[List[Item]] = rep(item)
}

// ItemParser.parse(ItemParser.items, "{{foo}}")
// res5: ItemParser.ParseResult[List[Item]] = 
// [1.8] parsed: List(Item(LeftDelim,{{), Item(Identifier,foo), Item(RightDelim,}}))
```

Adding whitespace skipping, or configurable left and right delimiters is trivial.

Comment: actually the beauty of the lex.go version is that it doesn't use regex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE

Comment: @Blankman you can rewrite the example using [`PackratParsers`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers). Then you'd need to exercise typing a bit more:  `left`, `right` and `ident` will look different, but `item` and `items` would still be the same. That's the beauty of parser combinators.